# Removing object from parent environment using rm()

Tags: r

I am trying to remove an object from the parent environment.

```
rm_obj <- function(obj){
  a <-deparse(substitute(obj))
  print (a)
  print(ls(envir=sys.frame(-1)))  
  rm(a,envir=sys.frame(-1))
}
> x<-c(1,2,3)
> rm_obj(x)
[1] "x"

[1] "rm_obj" "x"    
Warning message:
In rm(a, envir = sys.frame(-1)) : object 'a' not found
```

This will help clarify my misunderstanding regarding frames.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Surely `rm(x)` would be easier here.

Comment: Hi Dirk,

That is what I started with. However, ls() outside the function showed that the object was still there. I imagine that means that rm(x) inside the function simply operates on the local copy?? Again I could be wrong. Would appreciate if someone could explain why that happens. I would really try to understand it.

Russ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your frames are right I think, it's just that `rm` is trying to remove `a` itself instead of evaluating `a` to get the quoted name of the variable to remove.  Use the `list` parameter instead:

```
rm(list=a,envir=sys.frame(-1))
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan,

That worked. Would this be a proper way of eliminating large objects after they are no longer useful??
 
Russ

Comment: Why not just use `rm` directly in that case?

Comment: Oh! Now I see what Dirk meant. 
I am experimenting with freeing externally allocated memory (c/external-pointer) explicitly. My actual function is like 
free_ext_obj <-function(extptr){
.Call("free_ext_obj", extptr)
 a <-deparse(substitute(extptr))
 rm(list=a,envir=sys.frame(-1))
}
This allows me to free external resource and remove "extptr". I have also tried using finalizer. However, I wanted something explicit so that the externally allocated memory can be freed before gc() is invoked. Is this a reasoanble approach? This is intended more as an internal function. Thanks.  Russ

Comment: what if I want to remove somthing in the 'grandparent' environment?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me.

```
myEnv = new.env()
assign('xx', 5, envir=myEnv)
get('xx', envir=myEnv)
rm('xx', envir=myEnv)
```